# string is not getting exploded

Tags: php, codeigniter-3, explode

Here is my code where explode function is not getting correctly.code looks like this

```
 <div id="demo-1" data-zs-src='[<?php foreach( $slides as $slide ){?>"<?php echo base_url();?>uploads/<?php echo $slide->image;?>"<?php }?>]' data-zs-overlay="dots">
<div class="demo-inner-content">
  <h1><span>Tasty</span> & <span>Healthy</span></h1>
  <p>For those who have taste for life.</p>
</div>
```

my result looks like this

```
<div id="demo-1" data-zs-src='["http://localhost/fahiz_kitchen/uploads/upload-file1496902770.jpg""http://localhost/fahiz_kitchen/uploads/upload-file1496901910.gif""http://localhost/fahiz_kitchen/uploads/upload-file1496901900.jpg""http://localhost/fahiz_kitchen/uploads/upload-file1496901887.jpg"]' data-zs-overlay="dots">
<div class="demo-inner-content">
  <h1><span>Tasty</span> & <span>Healthy</span></h1>
  <p>For those who have taste for life.</p>
</div>
</div>
```

i want to get comma in between the result that means my result should be like this

```
<div id="demo-1" data-zs-src='["http://localhost/fahiz_kitchen/uploads/upload-file1496902770.jpg",
"http://localhost/fahiz_kitchen/uploads/upload-file1496901910.gif",
"http://localhost/fahiz_kitchen/uploads/upload-file1496901900.jpg",
"http://localhost/fahiz_kitchen/uploads/upload-file1496901887.jpg"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some changes i got the result and the code used for that is as follows

```
<?php foreach ( $slides as $slide ) {
$data[] = $images='"'.base_url()."uploads/". $slide->image.'"';
$y=implode(',',$data);
}?>
<div id="demo-1" data-zs-src='[<?php echo $y;?>]' data-zs-overlay="dots">
<div class="demo-inner-content">
  <h1><span>Tasty</span> & <span>Healthy</span></h1>
  <p>For those who have taste for life.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Chnage it like.

```
 $data = [<?php 
    foreach( $slides as $slide ){
     ?>"<?php echo base_url();?>uploads/<?php echo $slide->image;?>",
   <?php }?>];
$finaldata = rtrim($data, ',');

<div id="demo-1" data-zs-src="'.$finaldata.'" data-zs-overlay="dots">
<div class="demo-inner-content">
  <h1><span>Tasty</span> & <span>Healthy</span></h1>
<p>For those who have taste for life.</p>
</div>
```

You are starting php inside already started it.

Comment: when i used your code am getting like this Message: Array to string conversion

Comment: Can you try like that?
[<?php foreach( $slides as $slide ){?>"<?php echo base_url();?>uploads/<?php echo $slide->image;?>",<?php }?>]

Comment: at that time last one comma will come so it wont work otherwise its fine

Comment: $data = [<?php foreach( $slides as $slide ){?>"<?php echo base_url();?>uploads/<?php echo $slide->image;?>"<?php }?>]; 
$finaldata = rtrim($data, ',');
 <div id="demo-1" data-zs-src="'.$finaldata.'" data-zs-overlay="dots">

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146252/discussion-between-ajay-korat-and-user-777).

Answer (score 0):

plz use this;

```
<?php foreach( $slides as $slide ){ 
     $images= base_url()."uploads/". $slide->image;
     var_dump($images);
     $arr= explode(',',$images);
     print_r($arr);
}

?>
```